# How do you find your GitLab host name (to test your SSH key)?

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I just created a personal GitLab account and am trying to follow the steps on

https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README

to deploy my SSH key to GitLab. I've completed up to step 5, and see my SSH key among 'Your SSH keys' in my User Settings -> SSH keys:

[image]

I'm trying to now complete the optional 6th step, testing the key:

[image]

My GitLab username is `khpeek`, so I guessed my 'GitLab domain' is `gitlab.com/khpeek`. However, the test command

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com/khpeek
```

yields an error message:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.com/khpeek: Name or service not known
```

Apparently this is the wrong hostname. What would be the right one?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you're using Gitlab on gitlab.com then the domain is simply `gitlab.com` so you should run `ssh -T git@gitlab.com`

Comment: If you're behind a proxy and you need to configure your *vim ~/.ssh/config*  please note the hostName:
`Host gitlab.com
  HostName altssh.gitlab.com`

Comment: Thank you so much @aemonge you saved me so much time. I had tried recreating ssh keys, all sorts.

Answer (score 3):

Go to clone with ssh. And check the URL link. It should looks like this. git@hostname:project.git.  git@hostname this whole part is your hostname.

Comment: clear, was looking for a way to find it and this made it!

Answer (score 0):

Open your GitLab account or repository online (any site will do, just make sure your logged in). Then checkout the URL. The domain together with the TLD will be your hostname. E.g.

```
www.gitlab.your.institution.com/...
```

So in this case `gitlab.your.institution.com` is your hostname.